# How to parse json in javascript having dynamic key value pair?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse a JSON string in JavaScript. The response is something like

```
var response = '{"1":10,"2":10}';
```

How can I get the each key and value from this json ?

I am doing this -

```
var obj =  $.parseJSON(responseData);
console.log(obj.count);
```

But i am getting `undefined` for `obj.count`.

Comment: To get the no. of elements count use `Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: @Tushar And if i want key and value then how can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To access each key-value pair of your object, you can use `Object.keys` to obtain the array of the keys which you can use them to access the value by [ ] operator. Please see the sample code below:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    var value = obj[key];
    console.log(key + ':' + value);
});
```

Output:

> 1 : 10
>
> 2 : 20

`Objects.keys` returns you the array of the keys in your object. In your case, it is `['1','2']`. You can therefore use `.length` to obtain the number of keys.

```
Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Answer (score 5):

So you need to access it like an array, because your keys are numbers. See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7f5k9het

You can access like this:

```
 result[1] // this returns 10
 result.1 // this returns an error
```

Good luck