# Parsing JSON API with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl, foreach

I am working on the BooksRun API, and I can not  display any data returned from the API using a PHP foreach.  My code is below. Thanks in advance!

[BooksRun API Reference](https://booksrun.com/page/api-reference)

```
<?php
//PARAMETERS
$url = 'https://booksrun.com/api/v3/price/buy/0134093410?key=0t8rfbno7qc4lmaav9yz';

$headers = array(
"Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: \"run\""
 ); 

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
//Json Data decoded on PHP object
$obj_data = json_decode($result);

echo '<div>' . 'start : '.$obj_data->result->status . '</div>';
//echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$obj_data->result->offers->booksrun->new->price . '</div>';
//echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$obj_data->result->marketplace->used->price . '</div>';

foreach ($obj_data->result as $book) {
//fetch object data

echo '<div>' . 'seller: '.$book->offers->booksrun->rent->price . '</div>';
echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$book->marketplace->used->price . '</div>';

  }
?>
```

Comment: did you checked value of `$obj_data` ? anything coming in that? do `var_dump($obj_data)`; and check. Let us know what you got?Possibility is you are getting nothing

Comment: Dont post your original key here, and you dont need to loop through `result `

Comment: There's a key `"35"` after `"rent"`, so it should be `->rent->{"35"}->price`. I don't know what that 3t5 is, or if it changes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need change the code because there  is  an array in json 
maybe you can change into this code

```
<?php
//PARAMETERS
$url = 'https://booksrun.com/api/v3/price/buy/0134093410?key=0t8rfbno7qc4lmaav9yz';

$headers = array(
"Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: \"run\""
 ); 

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
//Json Data decoded on PHP object
$obj_data = json_decode($result);
echo '<div>' . 'start : '.$obj_data->result->status . '</div>';
//echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$obj_data->result->offers->booksrun->new->price . '</div>';
//echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$obj_data->result->marketplace->used->price . '</div>';

//fetch object data
foreach ($obj_data->result->offers->booksrun->rent as $rent) {
    echo '<div>' . 'seller: '.$rent->price . '</div>';
}
foreach ($obj_data->result->offers->marketplace as $marketplace) {
    echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$marketplace->used->price. '</div>';
}
?>
```

the problem in your code is you want to open an object but actualy it's an array

Answer (score 1):

Just make the following changes :

```
echo '<div>' . 'seller: '.$obj_data->result->offers->booksrun->rent->{"35"}->price . '</div>';
echo '<div>' . 'date: '.$obj_data->result->offers->marketplace[0]->used->price . '</div>';
```

`$obj_data->result->offers->marketplace` is an array so you can loop over this.

There is no need for looping over the result object as it only has one item in it.

Comment: What if the JSON dataset is sometimes a single result and sometimes and array?  Also it seems to me the API dynamically displays the {"35"}, so the number changes all the time... kinda seems stupid to me, but they must have a reason for it...

Comment: If dataset returns multiple values then you will have to use foreach loop. Also if you are looking for dynamic key parsing then kindly refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285360/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript-having-dynamic-key-value-pair

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful if you add

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

after

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: Because the API is HTTPS, this option allows you to skip the validation of the peer's certificate and get the $result.

Comment: Thank u buddy.That's a great suggestion.